# Getting textbox id of an applet without knowing it

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I'm having an applet in which the class name is known but the text box fields and other controls and their ids are not known.

Now i need to get the id of the textbox or the total controls exists in the applet from javascript or some java code.

Comment: How come you don't know the IDs of controls here? Are you trying to access an applet you don't own? In which case, you're trying to defeat the sandbox premise.

Comment: Where did you get the applet?  Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to say the text boxes (and whatnot) are part of the Java applet -- these are *not* HTML elements (although they may look similar), so they are not directly accessible from JavaScript. The applet may provide indirect access to them via LiveConnect, but by default there is no interface provided.

Comment: that is functions in the applet